# Delete archived items in Kindle 4 (through Amazon.com)

Tags: amazon, kindle

I'd like to permanently delete all my archived items (actually purge my Amazon.com account out of all previous content). I have found a dozen of guides on how to do this (which basically narrows to finding particular item and selecting `Delete` from context menu).

The problem is, that when I login to my Amazon.com account and go to [`Manage Your Content and Devices`](https://www.amazon.com/mn/dcw/myx.html/ref=nav_youraccount_myk) in `Your Content` tab I can only see my currently purchased books and there is absolutely not even a trace of all these items, by Kindle 4 shows in `Archived Items` folder.

So, how can I get my hands on `Archived Items` folder through my Amazon.com account, so I would be able to permanently delete these items / purge this folder?

Comment: "docs" is where sent-to-kindle shows for me.